# AAD graph api usageLocation eq null filter query not supported

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Graph explorer returns unsupported query when I execute

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,usageLocation&$filter=usageLocation+eq+null`

However, the filter for null on usageLocation should be supported according to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http

Am I missing something, or is the documentation wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

When I ran **same query** as you in Graph Explorer, I too got **same error** like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,usageLocation&$filter=usageLocation+eq+null
```

**Response:**

[image]

As mentioned in this [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http#legend),

> [image: Requires advanced query parameters.]
> The  `$filter`  operator  **requires**  *advanced query parameters*,
> which are:
> `ConsistencyLevel=eventual`  header
> and   `$count=true`  query string

To **resolve** the error, you need to add *advanced query parameters* like below:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,usageLocation&$filter=usageLocation+eq+null&$count=true
ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

**Response:**

[image]